# Iterating through a dictionary and subtracting values based on keys

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

So I have a dictionary like the one below, however, I am trying to subtract ART[0][0] - ART[1][0] and this has to be an iteration.

This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting the error: 'KeyError: 2'

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   for i in range(1, 5): #from
      k = i
      for j in range (1, 5): #to
           if i == j:
              pass
           else:
               t = ART[j][0] - ART[i][0]
               g = ART[j][1] - ART[i][1]
```

Sample input:

> ART = {'U': (5, 6),  'E': (7, 3),  'A': (3, 3),  'O': (3, 2),  'I':
>   (1, 4)}

Comment: You have not shown your expected result

Comment: Is the else block indented as you show? because that is wrong.  Indent the lines below it

Comment: I need to subtract the two values based on the key so my expected output is t=3 and g=-3

Comment: Your dictionary keys are the letters, and the tuples are the values stored against the key. But you are trying to use indices on a dictionary. I don't think this is the data structure that you want for ART.

Comment: And even if you swap the dictionary structure of `ART` around, so that the tuple values are the key and the letter is the value, the output would be nonsense because you'd be subtracting letters.

Comment: Can I change the dictionary keys in some way that allows me to call them based on indices?

Comment: Or is there a way to enumerate the dictionary keys so that they can be called based on indices?

Comment: No, you should research dictionaries to get a better understanding http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm. You could set the tuple as the key e.g. get the letter `U` based on `ART[(5, 6)]`. But currently it's impossible to understand what you are trying to do. As from the first comment, you need to show your expected result. It's not clear at all what `ART` is even for. You have picked letters simply to make keys for the sake of keys? You probably want a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are accessed by the key name. See [here](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files) for examples.

For example, `ART['U']` would return `(5, 6)`. In your code, you're trying to access a key `2`, because that's what `j` is equal to. However, there is no key named `2` in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to get all the combinations of keys from the dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered, so `ART[0]` does not have any meaning<sup>1)</sup>. Instead, you can iterate the keys directly:

```
for i in ART:
    for j in ART:
        if i != j:
            t = ART[j][0] - ART[i][0]
            g = ART[j][1] - ART[i][1]
```

Or shorter, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for i, j in itertools.product(ART, repeat=2):
    if ...
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Except if you have a key `0` in your dictionary, which you don't.

Comment: I get the impression that the letters are superfluous and the OP is really looking for a list of tuples as the data structure.

Comment: @roganjosh Maybe, but I don't think so. After all, the keys are all the vowels, that might have some meaning.

Comment: Comments ask for indexing and enumerating dictionary. I've put another answer in the meantime but we may never know :)

Answer (score 0):

You mention in comments that you want to call items in the dictionary by an index. This is not possible because dictionaries are unordered. Dictionaries are for mapping a particular 'key' to a value that you stored against that key. If you `print ART` several times, you will see different ordering. I don't think you want a dictionary here and I believe you've picked letters to make keys for the sake of making keys.

Python uses zero indexing. So `range(1, 5)` would miss the first item in a *list* if you were iterating through. You would want `for x in range(0, 5)` to get all elements in the list, which can be written simply as `for x in range(5)`.

Finally, your code has `i`, `j`, `k` (never used), `t` and `g`. This makes things **much** harder to understand, especially when Python gives you so much flexibility in naming things.

With those assumptions, I think you want a list of tuples as your data structure:

```
ART = [(5, 6), (7, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (1, 4)]
for i, item in enumerate(ART):
    for j, pair_item in enumerate(ART):
        if i != j:
            t = item[0] - pair_item[0]
            g = item[1] - pair_item[1]
```

Comment: Note that this might not work in all cases. Consider a list like `[(1,2),(3,4),(1,2)]`. OP is checking whether the indices are different, so he probably would want to handle the `(1,2), (1,2)` pair as well, but yours will skip it. Maybe use `enumerate` instead to get and compare the indices?

Comment: @tobias_k Noted and made change accordingly. Thanks.